# Brute Force Algorithm char set issues - index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, brute-force

I've made a brute force cracker in Java that you give a hashed (SHA1) password and it iterates through a given charset until it finds the correct password.

My first charset consists of:

```
"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

And the second charset of:

```
"9876543210zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"
```

The first char set works like a dream but as soon as I change any part of the order of the charset it causes the program to crash complaining about index out of bounds. I'm certain it's to do with the increment method but I'm not sure how to adapt it to fit my needs of needing to be able to iterate through multiple char sets.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, here's some sample code to give you an idea:

```
    char[] charsetA = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray(); 
    char[] charsetB = "9876543210zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba".toCharArray(); 

    charset = charsetA; // charsetA works but not charsetB

    BruteForce bf = new BruteForce(hashPassword, charset, 1);
    String attempt = bf.toString();
    attempt = pd.calcSha1(attempt);
    while (true) {
        if (attempt.equals(hashPassword)) {
            System.out.println("Password Found!");
            System.out.println("Password as plaintext : " + currentGuess);
            break;
        }
        attempt = bf.toString();
        currentGuess = attempt;
        attempt = pd.calcSha1(attempt);
        bf.increment();
    }
}


private char[] cs;  // Character Set
private char[] cg;  // Current Guess
String hashPassword; // Password searching for

public BruteForce(String password, char[] characterSet, int guessLength) {
    hashPassword = password;
    cs = characterSet;
    cg = new char[guessLength];
    Arrays.fill(cg, cs[0]);
}

public void increment() {
    int index = cg.length - 1;
    //System.out.println("index = " + index);
    while (index >= 0) {
        if (cg[index] == cs[cs.length - 1]) {
            if (index == 0) {
                cg = new char[cg.length + 1];
                Arrays.fill(cg, cs[0]);
                break;
            } else {
                cg[index] = cs[0];
                index--;
            }
        } else {
            cg[index] = cs[Arrays.binarySearch(cs, cg[index]) + 1];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I'm trying to iterate through each char in the charset until it reaches the end of possible chars, when it does I then want to add another character and cycle through all possibilities of those two character combinations and so on until it has exhausted all possibilities up to 6 characters in length (7 characters upwards takes far to long).

The increment function above I got from a tutorial but I'm trying to figure out the code so it will accept any charset input.

Any tips or pseudo code is what I'm after.

Comment: You're trying to do a binary search on an unsorted array (reverse-sorted might as well be unsorted as far as `binarySearch` is concerned).

Comment: Aw dam... beat me to it. Its like where's wally of c#

Comment: What are you doing in increment(), anyhow? Can you explain the algorithm? It's not what I would have expected to see.